# Strange blue loading circle in front of a black background showing when testing a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently learning Flutter development through doing a [Udacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udacity) tutorial. While testing my app after adding new assets to it, a strange black screen with a neverending blue loading circle shows up.

Here a screenshot:

[image]

When does this screen appear? Or why? How I can make this go away?

I have tried resetting the Android emulator and removing updates to the code.

I have the code on GitHub: https://github.com/jonasxd360/hello_rectange/tree/cff4177593fadd3d21cd28a3b6eb4987d89581af

---

I was able to solve the issue, but I am not sure why it came up.

This is the file that caused the issue:

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'backdrop.dart';
import 'category.dart';
import 'category_tile.dart';
import 'unit.dart';
import 'unit_converter.dart';

/// Loads in unit conversion data, and displays the data.
///
/// This is the main screen to our app. It retrieves conversion data from a
/// JSON asset and from an API. It displays the [Categories] in the back panel
/// of a [Backdrop] widget and shows the [UnitConverter] in the front panel.
///
/// While it is named CategoryRoute, a more apt name would be CategoryScreen,
/// because it is responsible for the UI at the route's destination.
class CategoryRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoryRoute();

  @override
  _CategoryRouteState createState() => _CategoryRouteState();
}

class _CategoryRouteState extends State<CategoryRoute> {
  Category _defaultCategory;
  Category _currentCategory;
  // Widgets are supposed to be deeply immutable objects. We can update and edit
  // _categories as we build our app, and when we pass it into a widget's
  // `children` property, we call .toList() on it.
  // For more details, see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27755
  final _categories = <Category>[];
  // TODO: Remove _categoryNames as they will be retrieved from the JSON asset
  static const _categoryNames = <String>[
    'Length',
    'Area',
    'Volume',
    'Mass',
    'Time',
    'Digital Storage',
    'Energy',
    'Currency',
  ];
  static const _baseColors = <ColorSwatch>[
    ColorSwatch(0xFF6AB7A8, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFF6AB7A8),
      'splash': Color(0xFF0ABC9B),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFFFD28E, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFFFD28E),
      'splash': Color(0xFFFFA41C),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFFFB7DE, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFFFB7DE),
      'splash': Color(0xFFF94CBF),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFF8899A8, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFF8899A8),
      'splash': Color(0xFFA9CAE8),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFEAD37E, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFEAD37E),
      'splash': Color(0xFFFFE070),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFF81A56F, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFF81A56F),
      'splash': Color(0xFF7CC159),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFD7C0E2, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFD7C0E2),
      'splash': Color(0xFFCA90E5),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFCE9A9A, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFCE9A9A),
      'splash': Color(0xFFF94D56),
      'error': Color(0xFF912D2D),
    }),
  ];

  //  Remove the overriding of initState(). Instead, we use
  // didChangeDependencies()
//  @override
//  void initState() {
//    super.initState();
//    for (var i = 0; i < _categoryNames.length; i++) {
//      var category = Category(
//        name: _categoryNames[i],
//        color: _baseColors[i],
//        iconLocation: Icons.cake,
//        units: _retrieveUnitList(_categoryNames[i]),
//      );
//      if (i == 0) {
//        _defaultCategory = category;
//      }
//      _categories.add(category);
//    }
//  }

  // Uncomment this out. We use didChangeDependencies() so that we can
  // wait for our JSON asset to be loaded in (async).
    @override
    Future<void> didChangeDependencies() async {
      super.didChangeDependencies();
      // We have static unit conversions located in our
      // assets/data/regular_units.json
      if (_categories.isEmpty) {
        await _retrieveLocalCategories();
      }
    }

  /// Retrieves a list of [Categories] and their [Unit]s
  Future<void> _retrieveLocalCategories() async {
    // Consider omitting the types for local variables. For more details on Effective
    // Dart Usage, see https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage
    final json = DefaultAssetBundle
        .of(context)
        .loadString('assets/data/regular_units.json');
    final data = JsonDecoder().convert(await json);
    if (data is! Map) {
      throw ('Data retrieved from API is not a Map');
    }
    // TODO: Create Categories and their list of Units, from the JSON asset
  }

  /// Function to call when a [Category] is tapped.
  void _onCategoryTap(Category category) {
    setState(() {
      _currentCategory = category;
    });
  }

  /// Makes the correct number of rows for the list view, based on whether the
  /// device is portrait or landscape.
  ///
  /// For portrait, we use a [ListView]. For landscape, we use a [GridView].
  Widget _buildCategoryWidgets(Orientation deviceOrientation) {
    if (deviceOrientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return CategoryTile(
            category: _categories[index],
            onTap: _onCategoryTap,
          );
        },
        itemCount: _categories.length,
      );
    } else {
      return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3.0,
        children: _categories.map((Category c) {
          return CategoryTile(
            category: c,
            onTap: _onCategoryTap,
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    }
  }

  // TODO: Delete this function; instead, read in the units from the JSON asset
  // inside _retrieveLocalCategories()
  /// Returns a list of mock [Unit]s.
  List<Unit> _retrieveUnitList(String categoryName) {
    // when the app first starts up
    return List.generate(10, (int i) {
      i += 1;
      return Unit(
        name: '$categoryName Unit $i',
        conversion: i.toDouble(),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_categories.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 180.0,
          width: 180.0,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }

    // Based on the device size, figure out how to best lay out the list
    // You can also use MediaQuery.of(context).size to calculate the orientation
    assert(debugCheckHasMediaQuery(context));
    final listView = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 8.0,
        right: 8.0,
        bottom: 48.0,
      ),
      child: _buildCategoryWidgets(MediaQuery.of(context).orientation),
    );
    return Backdrop(
      currentCategory:
      _currentCategory == null ? _defaultCategory : _currentCategory,
      frontPanel: _currentCategory == null
          ? UnitConverter(category: _defaultCategory)
          : UnitConverter(category: _currentCategory),
      backPanel: listView,
      frontTitle: Text('Unit Converter'),
      backTitle: Text('Select a Category'),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the same file without the issue:

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'backdrop.dart';
import 'category.dart';
import 'category_tile.dart';
import 'unit.dart';
import 'unit_converter.dart';

/// Loads in unit conversion data, and displays the data.
///
/// This is the main screen to our app. It retrieves conversion data from a
/// JSON asset and from an API. It displays the [Categories] in the back panel
/// of a [Backdrop] widget and shows the [UnitConverter] in the front panel.
///
/// While it is named CategoryRoute, a more apt name would be CategoryScreen,
/// because it is responsible for the UI at the route's destination.
class CategoryRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoryRoute();

  @override
  _CategoryRouteState createState() => _CategoryRouteState();
}

class _CategoryRouteState extends State<CategoryRoute> {
  Category _defaultCategory;
  Category _currentCategory;
  // Widgets are supposed to be deeply immutable objects. We can update and edit
  // _categories as we build our app, and when we pass it into a widget's
  // `children` property, we call .toList() on it.
  // For more details, see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27755
  final _categories = <Category>[];
  // TODO: Remove _categoryNames as they will be retrieved from the JSON asset
  static const _categoryNames = <String>[
    'Length',
    'Area',
    'Volume',
    'Mass',
    'Time',
    'Digital Storage',
    'Energy',
    'Currency',
  ];
  static const _baseColors = <ColorSwatch>[
    ColorSwatch(0xFF6AB7A8, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFF6AB7A8),
      'splash': Color(0xFF0ABC9B),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFFFD28E, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFFFD28E),
      'splash': Color(0xFFFFA41C),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFFFB7DE, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFFFB7DE),
      'splash': Color(0xFFF94CBF),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFF8899A8, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFF8899A8),
      'splash': Color(0xFFA9CAE8),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFEAD37E, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFEAD37E),
      'splash': Color(0xFFFFE070),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFF81A56F, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFF81A56F),
      'splash': Color(0xFF7CC159),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFD7C0E2, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFD7C0E2),
      'splash': Color(0xFFCA90E5),
    }),
    ColorSwatch(0xFFCE9A9A, {
      'highlight': Color(0xFFCE9A9A),
      'splash': Color(0xFFF94D56),
      'error': Color(0xFF912D2D),
    }),
  ];

  //  Remove the overriding of initState(). Instead, we use
  // didChangeDependencies()
//  @override
//  void initState() {
//    super.initState();
//    for (var i = 0; i < _categoryNames.length; i++) {
//      var category = Category(
//        name: _categoryNames[i],
//        color: _baseColors[i],
//        iconLocation: Icons.cake,
//        units: _retrieveUnitList(_categoryNames[i]),
//      );
//      if (i == 0) {
//        _defaultCategory = category;
//      }
//      _categories.add(category);
//    }
//  }

  // Uncomment this out. We use didChangeDependencies() so that we can
  // wait for our JSON asset to be loaded in (async).
    @override
    Future<void> didChangeDependencies() async {
      super.didChangeDependencies();
      // We have static unit conversions located in our
      // assets/data/regular_units.json
      if (_categories.isEmpty) {
        await _retrieveLocalCategories();
      }
    }

  /// Retrieves a list of [Categories] and their [Unit]s
  Future<void> _retrieveLocalCategories() async {
    // Consider omitting the types for local variables. For more details on Effective
    // Dart Usage, see https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage
    final json = DefaultAssetBundle
        .of(context)
        .loadString('assets/data/regular_units.json');
    final data = JsonDecoder().convert(await json);
    if (data is! Map) {
      throw ('Data retrieved from API is not a Map');
    }
    // TODO: Create Categories and their list of Units, from the JSON asset
  }

  /// Function to call when a [Category] is tapped.
  void _onCategoryTap(Category category) {
    setState(() {
      _currentCategory = category;
    });
  }

  /// Makes the correct number of rows for the list view, based on whether the
  /// device is portrait or landscape.
  ///
  /// For portrait, we use a [ListView]. For landscape, we use a [GridView].
  Widget _buildCategoryWidgets(Orientation deviceOrientation) {
    if (deviceOrientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return CategoryTile(
            category: _categories[index],
            onTap: _onCategoryTap,
          );
        },
        itemCount: _categories.length,
      );
    } else {
      return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3.0,
        children: _categories.map((Category c) {
          return CategoryTile(
            category: c,
            onTap: _onCategoryTap,
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    }
  }

  // TODO: Delete this function; instead, read in the units from the JSON asset
  // inside _retrieveLocalCategories()
  /// Returns a list of mock [Unit]s.
  List<Unit> _retrieveUnitList(String categoryName) {
    // when the app first starts up
    return List.generate(10, (int i) {
      i += 1;
      return Unit(
        name: '$categoryName Unit $i',
        conversion: i.toDouble(),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_categories.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 180.0,
          width: 180.0,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }

    // Based on the device size, figure out how to best lay out the list
    // You can also use MediaQuery.of(context).size to calculate the orientation
    assert(debugCheckHasMediaQuery(context));
    final listView = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 8.0,
        right: 8.0,
        bottom: 48.0,
      ),
      child: _buildCategoryWidgets(MediaQuery.of(context).orientation),
    );
    return Backdrop(
      currentCategory:
      _currentCategory == null ? _defaultCategory : _currentCategory,
      frontPanel: _currentCategory == null
          ? UnitConverter(category: _defaultCategory)
          : UnitConverter(category: _currentCategory),
      backPanel: listView,
      frontTitle: Text('Unit Converter'),
      backTitle: Text('Select a Category'),
    );
  }
}
```

Here the changes shown as a commit on GitHub: https://github.com/jonasxd360/hello_rectange/commit/957ffe0cb821d812a3bc6301623a5d6a2b33ee31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code. In your GitHub code, _categories is empty. That's why CircularProgressIndicator shows.

In file *category_route.dart*, change

```
if (_categories.isEmpty) {
    return Center(
        child: Container(
            height: 180.0,
            width: 180.0,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
    );
}
```

to

```
if (_categories.isEmpty) {
    return Center(
        child: Container(
        ),
    );
}
```

But the real issue is _categories is empty.

Comment: thank you, I thought the loading circle had something to do with the emulator, but I was wrong, it's in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this below code. `CircularProgressIndicator` wraps with `Scaffold`. It can overcome your issue.

```
if (_categories.isEmpty) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }
```